# OneLogin CRUD API for Apps

Tags: onelogin

I need to add/edit/delete OneLogin apps in tests runtime.

What api calls are supported for this?
I'm going to extend [onelogin.py](https://gist.github.com/foxwill/6578e2fe9f25e4270b94303c8e8225e5) for this.

[Get Apps for a User](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/get-apps-for-user) returns some apps structure, but still not full and user is required. I need to manage SAML apps in tests, to keep SAML regression support tests.

Comment: Not available yet, but it's on our roadmap.

What sort of apps were you interested in adding or were you looking for more of a hide / show existing apps functionality?

Comment: @JohnOffenhartz we could need this too. We have an internal project bootstrap tool for creating CMS projects. It would be nice, if this could add the login as app already on creation. And as we are using platform.sh the CI could create and delete a new app for the testing environments too.

Comment: @PatrikKarisch were looking for the ability to configure a form-based app or for SAML-based applications (or both)